# 3dconnexion mouse locks rotation when in Top view

Tags: 3d-view, navigation, orthographic, 3d-mouse, 3dconnexion

My Spacemouse locks up in any of the orthogonal views (Top, Left, Right, Front or Back). I have set Auto perspective on (and this works for my other input devices), but not for my 3d mouse. Which settings should I change so that I can rotate the top view to other non-aligned views and/ or rotate (roll) within the top view?

Answer (score 0):

In such a case it is always difficult to understand how your setup is built and how exactly this behavior is noticeable.

But maybe these screenshots can help you, which show a working setup.

[image]
*(Sorry for the language settings, unfortunately they can't be changed that easily.)*

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you go to top view? Does that lock your rotation axes as well?

Comment: The only real differences in my setup are that I use NDOF > Orbit for navigation and Turntable for rotation and different sensitivities, the rest is the same. And these other settings lock-up in top view too.

Comment: @Hologram Are you using a "Spacemouse" or "Spacemouse Pro"?

Comment: The Spacemouse Pro wireless

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the Spacemouse T/F/R buttons to switch to one of the orthographic views, but then use the controller to rotate straight back into a perspective view?

Before changing any setting in the 3DConnexion software, try this and see if it does what you want (assuming you have not remapped any of blender's default numpad key assignments):

- Switch to an orthographic view like Top/Front/Right using either the T/F/R buttons on the Spacemouse or [Numpad 7/3/1]
- Spacemouse control cap will let you pan and zoom but not rotate, i.e. you're locked into that iso view
- Press [Numpad 5] which will toggle back to a perspective view
- Now the Spacemouse will let you spin/roll/tumble/etc

If that's the behavior you're after, go into 3DConnexion settings and setup a macro named something like "Perspective Toggle" and just assign [Numpad 5] to it. Personally I assigned this macro to the top-left button in the group on the right where the other view buttons are. By default this button is supposed to "Roll CW" but that didn't seem to actually correspond to any actual blender command so I put my Perspective Toggle macro there instead.

[image: Screenshot of spacemouse settings]

Hope this is what you were looking for, enjoy!